# Can one use Shadowblade's "Unseen Weapon" on unarmed strikes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, unarmed-combat

> Unseen Weapon (Su): As a standard action, you can wrap any melee
> weapon you wield in a layer of shifting shadows. This causes the
> weapon to darken, become less distinct, and leave a trail of shadow
> behind it as it moves. Your weapon must be in hand and ready to use
> for you to draw upon this power. You can dismiss the effect with a
> free action; dropping or sheathing the weapon also ends the effect.

It specifies "any melee weapon **you wield**" and "Your weapon must be **in hand**", and I think fists and feet are not able to accomplish those requisites, but just in case, it doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the most pedantic and, honestly, terrible of DMs is going to prevent unseen weapon from working with unarmed strikes. The terms “wield” and “in hand” are generally used just to mean that you have to have the weapon in use, rather than sheathed or stored. And since unarmed strikes, and the warriors who use them, are simply weaker to begin with, and nothing about shadowblade synergizes in a stunningly powerful way with them, and the shadowblade itself is a weak prestige class, nixing this combination serves no purpose but pedantry, which is not a reason that a good DM would rule against it.